# ClickListener and InputHandler interfering

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx, listeners

I have a class called `InputHandler` which implements `InputProcessor` and is the `InputProcessor` for my Gameworld. That works just fine. But now I'm trying to built a main menu and my `clickListeners` do not work, but instead `touchDown()` from my `InputHandler`-class is called. I created an instance of all my screens to be able to switch between them easily but I have no idea how to fix that. I've heard of an `InputMultiplexer` but I have no plan how to integrate such a thing in my code to solve my problems. I tried to return false from my `touchDown()` and other methods but my `ClickListeners` don't do anything at all even after that.

Here is my code:

1st my "Main"Class where I create all the screens:

```
public void create(){   
    mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
    gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
    setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
}
```

the game class with its inputProcessor:

```
public GameScreen(final Stapler gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, StaplerValues.WORLD_GRAVITY), true);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world));
```

my InputHandler:

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

```
World world;

public InputHandler(World world) {
    this.world = world;
}

public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    // this is called even when i'm in my main menu and want to click a button
    return false;
}

public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    // your touch up code here

    return false; // return true to indicate the event was handled
}

public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {

    return false;
}
```

and my main menu with its clickListeners:

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

```
public MainMenuScreen(final Stapler gam) {
    game = gam;

    stage = new Stage();
    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    // Add widgets to the table here.

    TextureRegion upRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("boxLila.png")));
    TextureRegion downRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("boxGruen.png")));
    BitmapFont buttonFont = new BitmapFont(
            Gdx.files.internal("fonts/bodoque.fnt"), false);

    buttonFont.setScale(2);

    TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(upRegion);
    style.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(downRegion);
    style.font = buttonFont;

    play = new TextButton("Play", style);

    play.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
        }
    });

    // add the button with a fixed width
    table.add(play).width(500);
    // then move down a row
    table.row();

}
```

The click listener works but only if i didnt create an instance of GameWorld in the first place. How can I solve that they grab the right input depending on which screen is currently shown? Please try give an answer as detailed as possible because I'm quite new to all that stuff. And sorry for that mess of code and my bad english an thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is globally only one InputProcessor for the entire game. When you call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world));`, it replaces the InputProcessor that you set in your MainMenuScreen class.

One simple solution is to just change the game's input processor every time you switch between screens (in the `show()` method).

If you want two InputProcessors to both work simultaneously, you need to combine them using an [InputMultiplexer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html), and set the multiplexer as your game's InputProcessor.